# Как узнать, является ли число полным квадратом?

Tags: javascript

Допустим, у меня есть число 9, мне нужно проверить, можно ли из него вычислить целочисленный корень, если да, результат - true, нет - false. 
Благодарю за помощь!

Comment: Извольте, не то чтобы программу, а саму суть, как можно проверить можно ли вычислить или нет, не обязательно код, сама идея. Не будьте так злы 

Comment: пробуйте `Math.sqrt`.

Comment: А вариант вычислить корень и посмотреть, целочисленный ли он получился, не подойдёт?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Вычислить квадратный корень
Округлить до ближайшего целого
Возвести в квадрат
Проверить, что совпадает с исходным числом.

Этот подход несколько более устойчив к ошибкам вычислений, чем просто проверка, что корень целый
Например, `sqrt(23230573032496482275618623685) % 1`  даст ноль, хотя число не точный квадрат.

Comment: При получении квадратного корня из числа `23230573032496482275618623685` вы получите в результате `152415789971041`. Если после этого вы возведёте это число в квадрат, то получите уже `2.323057303249648e+28`, что при сравнении с исходным числом вернёт 'false'.

Comment: Но исходное число - в любом случае не квадрат

Comment: Да, верно. Но я к тому, что при работе с большими числами тоже будут ошибки вычислений, и при вычислении корня, и при возведении в квадрат. Но это уже скорее особенности языка.

Answer (score 2):

Для вычисления квадратного корня:

```js
function calculate(number)
{
    let result = Math.sqrt(number);
    return (result % 1 === 0);
}

calculate(9); // true
calculate(5); // false
```

Для вычисления корня в n-ой степени:

```js
/**
 * @param {number} number заданное число
 * @param {number} exp показатель корня
 */
function calculate(number, exp)
{
    let result = Math.pow(number, 1/exp);
    return (result % 1 === 0);
}

calculate(8, 3); // true
```

Comment: не годится для больших чисел. Например, для 1000000000000000005 результат будет true, хотя это не квадрат.

Comment: @Эникейщик, вы перебощили. Javascript вообще не может представить `1000000000000000005` точно. Для целых меньше `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER` этот метод работает. Хотя и полагается на неочевидное место в стандарте IEEE-754.

Answer (score 0):

Вот образец на Python с логарифмической сложностью, работает для сколь угодно больших чисел. Алгоритм будет работать, если переделать его и для кубов, и высших степеней.

````
# код efimenkoav86
x1=2103820193476767943245325325543245320809217401**2# тестовые числа
x2=2819348091238409123094721904432432457893253254
def sqrt(x):
    a = 1
    i = 0
    while (a + 2 ** i) ** 2 < x:
        a += 2 ** i #приближаемся к значению корня со скоростью геометрической прогрессии
        i += 1
        if (a + 2 ** i) ** 2 > x:
            i = 0 #когда превысили значение, сбавляем скорость приближения
    while a * a < x: # мы уже максимально близки к корню, если он есть
        a += 1       #приблизимся со скоростью арифметической прогрессии
    return a
def is_square(x):
    return sqrt(x)**2==x
print(is_square(x1))
print(is_square(x2))
print(is_square(81))
print(is_square(183192044498750943795037209472317840923740273104973209470932750973240932709573257320974532097450392**2))```
````

Comment: `math.isqrt` делает ту же работу.

Answer (score 0):

Вот образец рекурсивной функции на языке С. Обычно тип int занимает 4 байта, поэтому будет работать с числами из диапазона от 0 до INT_MAX. Если нужно больший диапазон, то int можно заменить на unsigned long long int.

```
_Bool is_square(int n, int delitel) {
    if(n<=1 || delitel * delitel == n)
        return 1;
    if(delitel > n)
        return 0;
    return is_square(n, delitel+1);
}
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: Использование рекурсии здесь совершенно нецелесообразно.

Comment: Очень не эффективно.

Answer (score 0):

```
if pow(a, 0.5) % 10 == 0:
```

То есть, если корень этого числа имеет только целую часть, то это полный квадрат.

Comment: Ваш ответ можно улучшить с помощью дополнительной информации. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] для добавления подробностей, например, цитат или документации, чтобы другие могли подтвердить правильность вашего ответа. Вы можете найти дополнительную информацию о том, как писать хорошие ответы [в Справке](/help/how-to-answer).